# Raspberry Pi Voice Hat Costom Setup

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

i have the raspberry pi aiy kit as described with: https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice-v1/

i would like to use the voice hat by itself without the google ecosystem, but i am not able to find any guides of how to set up the voice hat on a fresh install of raspbian.

in the guide (https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice-v1/) it suggest to install its own image with etcher which works as expected, but im unable to find anything specific about the voice hat hardware on how to get feedback from the microphones and output to speaker.

i feel like hardware like this has some documentation on how to set it up on a vanilla install of raspbian but i am unable to find it. i have tried searching details on google, but the results seem to all be about setting it up with the provided image.

can anyone suggest resources for this?

(to further describe the scenario, the raspberry pi is in a docker-swarm cluster, to install a fresh image would mean to wipe out the sd-card to replace with the fresh install, which i would then need set up with docker and docker-warm... which i would like to avoid if possible.)

Comment: The only voice assistant I know of that is open source is Mycroft https://mycroft.ai/ but I do not know if it will work in your set up or do what you need...

Comment: thanks... it looks like it supports the same hardware... but it also seems to suggest using their own image. i will see if the code is easy enough to understand to install onto an existing raspbian installation after cloning the repo.